# How to generate image matrix (which contains pixel intensity value as a form of integer 2d array) from a grayscale image in Android.

Tags: android, image-processing

Each and every pixel contains a particular intensity value. In grayscale image it's from 0-255. In java I can do it very easily. But I don't know how to the same job in android. Like as input i am taking a grayscale image with 640x480 resolution, it will generate a matrix which row and column size will be 640 and 480 and each and every element of this array contains the perticular pixel intensity of the grayscale image. I tried using getpixel() i also used open cv for android. But cant do this job. Please help

Comment: Please provide more details. Can you post some code over here? Without that it's difficult to figure out where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried this: int[] imageDataArray = new int[height*width];
        bmpGrayscale.getPixels(imageDataArray, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        for(int i = 0; i< height*width; i++)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Samir Pixel" + i + imageDataArray[i]);
        }

Comment: I tried also this using opencv for android: for (int i = 0; i < imageMat.rows(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < imageMat.cols(); j++)
            {
                double[] imageData = imageMat.get(i,j);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a grayscale Bitmap bmp, all three RGB-components are equal. Thus, in order to get the intensity value for pixel (x,y) you just can access any component (red, gree, blue), for example like this:

```
    int pixel = bmp.getPixel(x,y);
    int intensity= Color.red(pixel);
```

Faster is the following:

```
  int data[] = new int data[width*height];
  bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < width*height; i++) {
    int p = pixels[i];
    int r = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
    //int g = (p & 0xff00) >> 8;
    //int b = p & 0xff;
    data[i] = r;
   }
```